# TinyMCE trouble when loading text (probably Ajax related)

Tags: php, tinymce

I have a textarea, this is the code:

```
<textarea id="mailtemplate4" class="mceEditor" rows="20" cols="139" name="templatearea4"></textarea>
```

I am using the tinyMCE Editor to display some text which gets generated in an Ajax request. Problem is, the editor shows up, but the text is never displayed, this is the code which is executed once the Ajax request has finished:

```
// this returns an object which has the right mce editor container and so on
var myControl = tinyMCE.get('mailtemplate4');
```

Now I am trying to set some text using this code:

```
myControl.setContent("some text");
```

This is not working and I am getting this execption:

Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIDOMHTMLDocument.implementation]" nsresult: "0x8000ffff ....

Why? I am loading the editor like this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector : "mceEditor",
    theme : "simple"   
});
```

It seems there are no JS errors.

Comment: can you output the variable myControl before you call myControl.setContent("some text");
 ??

Comment: Yes, I can see its values when debugging ... what value should I output? Its an object with many values...

Comment: ok, that's all i wanted to know. this means myControl is indeed the full editor object. what browser and version of tinymce are you using?

Comment: Its Firefox 13 and tinymce 3.2 Id say ... I cant update the version of tinymce. I also tried `tinyMCE.get('mailtemplate4').setContent("some text");`, this fails as well.

Comment: do you have the possibility to test it with another browser (like FF11 or IE8/IE9)?) some troubles only occur with special versions ?

Comment: setContent usually works everywhere... (but i thought it might be related to a version conflict). Updating tinymce might solve the issue. Why do you cannot update tinymce?

Comment: I tried updating...same issue.